# AmazonWebServiceClient.beforeMarshalling - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using aws cloudformation to check a stack:

```
val client = new AmazonCloudFormationClient()
val stackName = "myStack"
val describRequest = new DescribeStackEventsRequest
describRequest.withStackName(stackName)
val describResult = client.describeStackEvents(describRequest)
```

This code threw:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     
com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.beforeMarshalling(Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;
at com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.AmazonCloudFormationClient.describeStackEvents(checkStack.sc1577334117592745460.tmp:724)
at #worksheet#.describResult$lzycompute(checkStack.sc1577334117592745460.tmp:9)
at #worksheet#.describResult(checkStack.sc1577334117592745460.tmp:9)
at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(checkStack.sc1577334117592745460.tmp:9)
```

I am using 1.9.23 aws sdk. Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the dynamodb-transactions library by any chance?

I had this error when trying to call Tables.doesTableExist() and it only started once I included that library in my build path.

Removing the library got rid of the issue.

Not much use if you need that transactions library though I guess ...?!

Comment: Thanks. I am new to CloudFormation and started with the simplest. no, I don't use any other library.

Comment: I'd imagine my issue, at least, was caused by a clash on the classpath, i.e. picking up the wrong version of a class at runtime.  Could it be possible that is what is happening with your issue somehow?